# Apache-Shiro and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, shiro

We have a web application. We are using tomcat 7 ans shiro. The site working well on IE and Firefox, but not in Chrome:

Say we have 2 users: one is admin and can access the whole site. The other is guest and can access to only one part of the site. In Chrome, when I log in with admin account, everything works well. But if I log out, and then, logging in with guest account, I can access to the whole site... If I hard-refresh, then the accesses to restricted parts works again.

I don't understand why it happen on Chrome. Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution:

I add this Jquery method:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
});
```

It prevent the browser to caching.
Hope it can be usefull.